# when i called a POST call from Get its showing data in URL but i can't access this url data in POST NODEJS,ExpressJs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

```
router.get('/reset/:unique_url',function(req,res){

    var url=req.params.unique_url; 

    User.findOne({ 'unique_url' : url, "time_stamp": { $gt: Date.now() }},function(req,User){

        if(!User){
          console.log('Link has expired');
          return res.redirect('/forget');
        }
        else {
          console.log('Reset page');
         return res.render('reset');
        }
    });
});

router.post('/reset',function(req,res){
      console.log('enter password '+req.unique_url);
      User.findOneAndUpdate({'unique_url' :req.params.unique_url, "time_stamp": { $gt: Date.now() }},{$set:{"password":createHash(req.body.password)}},{new:false},
        function (err, doc) {
          if(!err)
            res.redirect('/');
          else {
             console.log('error '+err);
            }
         });
  res.redirect('/');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In GET method

**The query string (name/value pairs) is sent in the URL of a GET request:**

In Post method

**The query string (name/value pairs) is sent in the HTTP message body of a POST request:**

So for getting data in post request we use **body in place or params**